# Typescript types are not suggesting when passing prop values via function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I cant figure out how to write the types so the dev has the suggested types for the specific prop no matter how he passes the data to the prop.

As an example. I have a component and passing array of values via the prop:

```
<Component someProp={[{ fancyName: 'test' }]} />
```

Now if I pass it like this directly to the prop, I get auto suggested types when I start typing them, but if I do something like this:

```
somefunction = () => {
   return [{ fancyName: 'test' }]
}

<Component someProp={this.someFunction()} />
```

Then I dont get auto suggested types at all even tho the types apply.

And in the types I would have something like this:

```
export interface SomeTypes{
   someProp: Array<SecondTypes>
}

export interface SecondTypes{
   fancyName: string
}
```

In order to fix this I can do this:

```
somefunction = (): SomeTypes => {
   return [{ fancyName: 'test' }]
}
```

But then all the devs has to apply the types like this for the function and not all will. I want to force them to use the types and get suggestions even if they pass the values via function return. I hope the problem is clear and someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: Would inlining the value solve it? `<Component someProp={[{ fancyName: 'test' }]} />`

Comment: @NickMcCurdy that is what OP said first, but they want to also support the case where value is prepared somewhere else.

Comment: @ghybs Yes exactly. Some of the values might be prepared dynamically in the other files so I need to make sure any functions will inherit the return types with the suggestions

Comment: Does this help in any way? Same idea, different solution. 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQgFtgAVATzGAGcBvAKDieuOAAUoIwAuOAQShRM5ADz5g2CEgAmFKtQB89AL716oSLEQo0WXAQlTZlGgyZwsSbOQBymEr2owoyAOYq1MEwVYcu1ADEAVysYBCk4AF44AAoASiiFHxI5GgBuNXQQ7DCIlhI-MGoACUwZABs0GOxMcvKAIxwAa15CAs4i4NDwpASzOChgGCCoJDgausbsJviM1XoAegW4YCR0aFxqAaGRpAAaOHqg+EGARyCEQa389g6SsulKqDgg6kxXYHpJJCc4G66cj0on9fHdShUqvFErFaDdCrwANpwWiWax2BxwABEqCcmLgyjgAF1lHE4molis1hsaNthqM4F4qAcjvBMNJpFsst0IozPt9fv9snxyqhRpgwgA3YCtUH+AG5MbRKGRJIxWGynhwBEospo+zSrE4mCY5TEuJpIA

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [nominal typing](https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/).

Probably the most OOP-friendly nominally typed approach is to use custom model classes:

```
import { Component } from "react"

class Named {
  constructor(public fancyName: string) {}
}

class SomeComponent extends Component<{ someProp: Named[] }> {}

class TestComponent extends Component {
  someFunction = () => {
    return [new Named('test')]
  }
    
  render() {
    return <SomeComponent someProp={this.someFunction()} />
  }
}
```

Comment: That will not solve the issue as it means we have to restructure whole project and the component we are using it is being reused hundreds of times. I am looking for a solution strictly within the typescript file. Its strange how inline array with values works normally but the returned via function does not.

Comment: it's not strange. the function - when defining - can't know what it is supposed to return unless explicitly defined. it does not inherently know of its use case.

Comment: So how come if I do return within the function array of values which are not part of the ts types, the component returns an error saying that the types are incorrect. The only issue here is I have no autofill of these types

Comment: because it resolves the return type when called in the component prop (it expects a certain shape), but you won't have an error when defining the function with that different type of return.

Comment: its like you have a lock (your expected prop type). i can make millions of different keys (different functions with different return types) but when attempting to insert the key and unlock the lock, only the ones with the correct return type will actually unlock it. For the others it will complain that they dont fit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem then, since this seems to be a pretty clean solution to it. Are you trying to improve type safety with nominal types, or do you just want easier suggestions from your editor?

Comment: If you don't want to have an unnecessary wrapper type at runtime, then use type assertions with branded types. This has little to no JavaScript overhead at runtime, and if you're not ready to fix the type errors in a particular file, you can disable TypeScript on that file until you add brands.

Comment: Its not going to work since the solution is not strictly within the types. I am not looking for any wrappers or adding any type values near each function. We are looking for a solution within the types structure without touching any classes, functions etc. If its not possible, then its fine. Its just strange how the types are still applied for the returned values but not suggested

Comment: Brands only exist in types. There is no wrapper class in JavaScript.

Comment: The type you're returning doesn't have any named properties, so nothing can be suggested, unless you specify a type by using nominal typing (my suggestion) or explicit types (your original suggestion). The type is, however, still assignable, as its shape is compatible.

Answer (score -1):

With React Functional component you can do like this:

```
import { React, FC } from 'react';
          
interface IMyCompProps {   
 somefunction: () => SomeTypes 
}
          
const MyComp: FC<IMyCompProps> ({somefunction}) => {  
return <></> 
}
         
function myFunc() { 
  return [{ fancyName: 'test' }] 
}
         
<MyComp somefunction={myFunc}/>
```

and it should do the trick.

Comment: Problem is that we dont use FC, also I need the fix to be within the types script and not where the values are prepared

Comment: Well then you should use them, because it is a proper way to give types to Functional component props. JSX element usage is outdated. 

Class component accepts generics by default, if u use Class component

Comment: `FC` is bad practice, there's no reason why you can't use typed arguments here.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan Our product is very large and complicated, def not going to convert to FC once all product is written with classes, also I personally hate FC. I dont see any point using them at all for various reasons. We are using types in the project without any issues apart the one noted in OP.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy why FC is a bad practise? Maybe for React 18, implicit children. But it is helping to get typed components. 
 well then, pity it didn't help.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177